# Как сделать этот градиент для обводки кнопки что бы при этом фон кнопки остался прозрачный?

Tags: css, градиент

Не получаеться сделать этот градиент, то часть отлетает и остаеться перевернутая буква u, то только с двух сторон маленькие полоски остаються. Может это вообще нереально(совместить и градиент(как обводку) и прозрачный фон)?[image: Button]

Comment: Приложите код ваших попыток. Вариантов реализации много, можно взять градиент в картинку и подставить как значение `border-image`, можно кнопку реализовать с помощью `svg` фона

Comment: что мешает задать один цвет и странице и фону кнопки (эффект прозрачности), а обводку сделать градиентной?

Comment: https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/WNmXEPd